# How non-trinitarians explain Jacob wrestled with God

Tags: life-of-jesus, nature-of-god, old-testament

I want to know how different churches that does not believe in Jesus diety or pre-existence the verses from the OT:

> Genesis 32:24-30
>   Easy-to-Read Version (ERV)
>
> 24 Jacob was left alone, and a man came and wrestled with him. The man fought with him until the sun came up. 25 When the man saw that he could not defeat Jacob, he touched Jacob’s leg and put it out of joint.
>
> 26 Then the man said to Jacob, “Let me go. The sun is coming up.”
>
> But Jacob said, “I will not let you go. You must bless me.”
>
> 27 And the man said to him, “What is your name?”
>
> And Jacob said, “My name is Jacob.”
>
> 28 Then the man said, “Your name will not be Jacob. Your name will now be Israel.[a] I give you this name because you have fought with God and with men, and you have won.”
>
> 29 Then Jacob asked him, “Please tell me your name.”
>
> But the man said, “Why do you ask my name?” Then the man blessed Jacob at that place.
>
> 30 So Jacob named that place Peniel.[b] He said, “At this place, I saw God face to face, but my life was spared.”

And specifically how do they explain Jacob asking for the blessing from the man (verse 26), and the man blessing Jacob (verse 29)

Comment: This isn't exactly a trinity vs. non-trinity question. There are trinitarians who don't see interpret 'the man' in this passage as Jesus. And there are non-trinitarians who *do* see 'the man' as Jesus.

Answer (score 5):

Nontrinitarians disagree with the mainstream Christian understanding of the Trinity summarized by the Nicean council.

That does not preclude the existance of Jesus before the first century AD.

For example, Jehovah Witnesses believe Jesus was (and is) Michael the Archangel.

And Mormons believe that God the Father exists in the form of a man and that Jesus existed in the form of a man, even before his birth (Ether 3, Book of Mormon).

This is an interesting (confusing) scripture for several reasons, for example, in reconciling it with Exodus 33:20

> Thou canst not see my [God's] face: for there shall no man see me, and live.

but I don't see how Nontrinitarianism would of itself make this story more difficult to explain.

---

FYI, if you are looking for general interpretations, see

- [Why did God wrestle with Jacob?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/4082/why-did-god-wrestle-with-jacob?rq=1)
- [Why did God wrestle with Jacob and why did this appearance not become a "big deal"?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/8217/jacob-wrestled-with-god?rq=1)