# Do Catholics violate Torah laws?

Tags: catholicism, judaism, ten-commandments, torah, statues

As is well-known, Judaism rejects all statues based on the Torah. The Presbyterian Church and Protestants reject making statutes but Roman Catholics made many statues of Jesus, Mary, Peter, and Paul. Catholics go as far as to pray to Mary and the saints.

Isn’t this a violation of the Decalogue: “Thou shalt not make unto thee a graven image, nor any manner of likeness”?

---

This question is different from others as it assumes the Decalogue hasn't been lifted as others presuppose.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Has the prohibition against construction and veneration of statues and images been abrogated?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/54809/has-the-prohibition-against-construction-and-veneration-of-statues-and-images-be)

Comment: No, because my questions assume the Decalogue has not been lifted.

Comment: One of those answers responds to the very subject of the Decalogue.

Comment: @TurkHill asking about a Catholic practice based upon. a position which at least allegedly Catholicism doesn't hold is contradictory. It can't be answered

Comment: @eques Catholics do pray to statues, don't they?

Comment: No Catholics do not pray to statues! Statues represent real realities within Catholic belief, but still a statue is simply a statue. Does not a soldier kiss a photo of his wife while he is off to war? It is just a photo, but his heart yearns to see his wife!

Comment: @TurkHill as Ken already said, no, Catholics don't, but my point was more so you can't ask for a Catholic understanding on some theological point without also accepting a Catholic understanding of the Decalogue, the Torah, etc. Otherwise you are asking nonsense.

Comment: @Geremia This question is different than the linked-to one, since it assumes that Catholicism is at odds with its own belief that this law within the Torah is still binding.

Comment: @SolaGratia Yes, that is correct. Thank you.

Comment: @TurkHill I have an answer prepared should this be re-opened by the community. Spoiler: we do not violate this law of Moses.

Comment: @SolaGratia Yes, I hope they do re-open the answer. How does one petition it? I would like to see your answer.

Comment: @TurkHill Users with the vote to open/close must vote to do so. I've put in my vote.